# Change height of plot depending of number of groups for different input selections

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to changes the hight of my plot based on the number of variables (Column Cancer) that are in the dataset for a particular selection (V1). My gig-lot output is `p` an dI tried to get the number of groups using `out <- layer_data(p, 1)` then calculating the height of the plot using the formula `length(table(out$group))*50`, however, all plots are the same, irrespectively of how many categories I have in my V1 variable.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_selected <- reactive({
    filter(files.Vir.DNA.df.test, V1 %in% input$Taxa)
  })
  
  output$myplot1 <- renderPlot({
    #data_selected() %>%
    p <- ggplot(data_selected(),aes(position,rowSums, fill = Cancer)) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity") +
      facet_grid(Cancer~. , scales = "free_x", space = "free_x", switch = "x") +
      theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0),
            strip.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
            strip.background = element_rect(colour = "transparent", fill = "transparent"),
            plot.background = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = "white"),
            panel.background = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = "white"),
            
            axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) + 
      labs(y="", x="", title="") +
      scale_fill_manual(values=mycolors) + 
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      scale_y_log10(breaks=c(1,100,10000)) 
      print(p)
      out <- layer_data(p, 1)
    
  },res = 100,width = 600, height = length(table(out$group))*50)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't reproducible - so I made a new one. Please check the follwoing:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(datasets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("species", "Species", choices = unique(iris$Species), selected = unique(iris$Species), multiple = TRUE, options = list('plugins' = list('remove_button'))),
  fluidRow(plotOutput("myplot"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    iris[iris$Species %in% input$species,]
  })
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    scatter <- ggplot(data = filtered_data(), aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) 
    scatter + geom_point(aes(color=Species, shape=Species)) +
      xlab("Sepal Length") +  ylab("Sepal Width") +
      ggtitle("Sepal Length-Width")
  }, height = reactive({length(input$species)*200+200}))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```